# Was the sprouting of seeds for food production known in Europe before 1800?

Tags: cultural-history, food, medicine

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprouting 
Was this not known in Europe?

Comment: Why do you believe that it wasn't?

Comment: Because i found no reference to it - dit you?

Comment: You've simply been searching for the wrong term - see my answer below.

Comment: There is a reason the terms differ - see my answer below.

Comment: @HannesH Something seems to be missing - did you forget to post your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Beer is made by [fermenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewing) a [malt (or *mashed grain*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malt) such as barley. The process of [*malting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malting_process) begins identically as that of preparing *sprouts* for food, except it is then halted by drying.

Since beer-making in this way has been known to European and Middle Eastern cultures for thousands of years, then the process of *sprouting* was also known  to those same cultures.

Comment: Sure, but i am asking for sprouting for food production. Malting is a technique to make weeds that farmers had in the first place (and could have eaten anyway) into a source of sugar needed for alcohol production. I don't know of any refernce to this beeing a technique to produce a new kind of food (which in Asia, it was).

Comment: @HannesH: Beer ***is*** a food. One that is high in Vitamin E, just for starters.

Comment: @HannesH: Besides which - I'd rather have beer than sprouts anytime, any place. Not everyone enjoys them.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens beer is a food as in : a balanced diet is a pint in each hand ...

Comment: Yes, "The beer is a liquid bread of the Czech Nation" (citation from "Adela hadn't had her dinner yet"). And the direct use for food only had not sense - sprouts has less calories than grain.

Answer (score 0):

An example of solid food made from sprouted seeds is the Finnish speciality of [mämmi/memma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A4mmi), which is made from malted rye and traditionally eaten at Easter. It seems to be attested since at least the 18th century ([source](http://www.martat.fi/ruoka/reseptit/mammin-historia/) in Finnish, I used Google translate).